# Does the iteration $e_i^\top x_{t+1} = \max_j e_i^{\top} (\alpha A^j x_{t} + b^j)$ converge?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, dynamical-systems, control-theory, optimal-control

Given a constant $0 < \alpha < 1$, a matrix $A \in R^{n \times n}$ and a vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, it is well-known that a sufficient condition for the iteration $x_{t+1} = \alpha A x_t + b$ to converge is that the spectral radius of A is bounded by one.

This question concerns a generalization of this problem to the case where we have  a finite set of pairs $(A^j,b^j)$. Consider the set $A^R$ of matrices obtained by taking rows from the matrices $A^j$, i.e.  $A^R = \{ A: \forall r. \exists j. A^j_{r,:} = A_{r,:} \}$. Here by $A_{r,:}$ we denote the rth row of $A$. We assume that the joint spectral radius of the set $A^R$ is bounded by one, i.e. the spectral radius of any finite product of the elements of $A^R$ is at most one.

Now, consider the following iteration.

$ \forall i.  e_i^\top x_{t+1} = \max_j e_i^{\top} (\alpha A^j x_{t} + b^j)$

Here by $e_i$ we denote the canonical basis vector.

My questions are:

1. Given the condition that the joint spectral radius of the set $A^R$ is bounded by one, does this converge to a single value?
2. Does this converge to the same thing regardless of the starting value?
3. If it doesn't converge to a single value, does it converge to a limiting cycle (i.e. a periodic orbit)?

Note: This is a generalized version of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161826/still-open-convergence-of-a-certain-matrix-product-representing-a-class-of-pie) question, where the difference is in a weaker condition on the $A_j$s.

I would also be very grateful for hints or incomplete solutions.

Comment: Why do you consider complicated condition 1) instead of just supposing that every matrix $A_j$ has norm less than $1$ (or equivalently has spectral radius less than one)?

Comment: @demitau Because multiplying two matrices with spectral radius less than one can be a matrix with spectral radius more than one. It would be enough to assume that a single sub-multiplicative norm exists which is one for all the $A$s but this is sometimes too conservative.